# Using sar command results in wrong memory statistics on Fedora 22

Tags: linux, shell, fedora, sar, free-command

I'm trying to monitor a few servers by gathering various information with `sar`. All the systems which should be monitored are currently running Fedora 22. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get correct memory readings.

**> free:**

              `total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1017260       34788      150984          68      831488      816204
Swap:        524284       20960      503324`

**> sar -r 1:**

`kbmemfree kbmemused %memused kbbuffers kbcached kbcommit %commit kbactive kbinact   kbdirty
150996    866264    85.16    40        60784    169524   11.00   39572    31068     164`

How does sar come up with those numbers? `kbmemfree` seems alright and `kbmemused` also makes sense if you add `used` and `buff/cache` from `free` together. But `kbbuffers` and `kbcached` look way off - my assumption is `kbmemused - kbbuffers - kbcached = used (output of free)`, but that doesn't match up.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm struggling with that issue since two days now and wasn't able to find any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

free from the procps tools seems to add `Slab:` from `/proc/meminfo` to its cached output. See proc/sysinfo.c kb_main_cached

So to get the equivalent output from sar you have add `kbcached` and `kbslab` from `sar -r ALL 1` together.